# Access pycharm server from anywhere on the internet

Tags: python, webserver, django, pycharm

I am working on a django project and want to show current state of project quickly to the client. Currently i can access develpement sever using the following URL.

http://localhost:42333/my_project

and this is what i want to do:

http://myip(:port-optional)/my_project

Comment: Is there any other quick solution ? For e.g in Apache server i have to remove few lines from http.conf file and viola server is available to anyone on the internet. Another point is dyndns is not free service. I need quick and dirty solution.

Comment: downvoter pls comment what's wrong with the question ?

Comment: maybe teamviewer?